# Boost Regex for extracting key value pairs

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Planning to develop a utility using boost and regex to extract key value pairs in a string.

Sample input string could be as follows

> travel:1.5,car insurance:3.25

After extraction should look like

> travel          1.5
>
> car insurance   3.25

Have the following code , but somehow this seems to be not working as expected

```
 std::map<std::string, std::string> pairs;
  boost::regex re("(?:(.*?):(.*?),)*(?:(.*?):(.*?))$"); // key - value pair

  // read lines from stdin; populate map
  boost::sregex_iterator it(str.begin(), str.end(), re), end;
  for ( ; it != end; ++it){
      pairs[(*it)[1]] = (*it)[2];
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just split by `,` and then by `:`? Otherwise a simple regex such as `([^:]+):([^,]+)` will suffice, where the first backreference is your key and the second your value.

Comment: thanks lindrain ,tried ([^:]+):([^,]+) then we get results like 'travel  1.5' and ',car insurance 3.25' except fro the first key all other keys have ',' in them

Comment: tried rectifying the issue using regex "(?:([^:]+):([^,]+)[,])" , but now all key-values get extracted as expected but for last key value pair which does not end with a ',' delimiter

Comment: Just add an optional comma to one of those expressions, then. If you use ([^:]+):([^,]+),? then it will match key-value lists with a redundant comma at the end, which might be considered a feature.

Answer (score 0):

This really shouldn't be that difficult. You already have most of the answer, it's just a matter of handling the last comma. `(:,|$)` should work quite nicely.

`(?:([^:]+):([^,]+)(?:,|$))+`